# Azure DevOps - Hide certain extensions/ action items from Reader permission group

Tags: azure, azure-devops, permissions

we have installed the extension "retrospectives" in our Azure DevOps projects(in the board section). Since our customer has access to the board (permission group "Reader") we would ideally like to hide this extension from them since retrospectives should be some kind of a safe place for the dev team. Also, we are tracking improvement actions via action items of the type "improvement" in our board. It would also be great to hide those.

What I tried so far: in the project settings you can edit the permissions but its very limited to not moving items for example, also the organization settings do not provide any suitable options. I also looked into the security section for the extension for example but no help either.

Ideally: the Reader-Group has access to the board but cant see the extension "Retrospectives" and also cant see the action items of the type "improvement". It appears to me that there is no way but maybe there is some kind of a backdoor somewhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- As far as I know, we don't have the option to hide the extensions or action items from the permission group we do have only user-level permissions of a particular person to allow or deny a few options in project settings.

1. Add users to your organization with basic access.

Go to **Organization** settings->**Security**->**Permission**->**Users**->**Select** the user and deny All his permission.

2. Add this user to the Readers group of your Project

Go to the **project settings**->**Permissions**->Select **Readers** group->**Add** this user

- Here is the [document](https://devtks.github.io/img/retrospective/retrospective.pdf) related to Retrospectives.